# when i try to connect github repo and travis ci, there is error

Tags: travis-ci

im studying ' how to connect between github and travis. and my os is windows.

i made '.travis.yml' file, dockerfile, Dockerfile.dev in react app(vsc)

and there is error on travis web site after i push on github this app. like this.

```
      4 | test('renders learn react link', () => {
      5 |   render(<App />);
    > 6 |   const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
        |                              ^
      7 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      8 | });
      9 |
      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:37:19)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at getByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:6:30)
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |    9.09 |        0 |   33.33 |    9.09 |                   
 App.js             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js           |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 7-17              
 reportWebVitals.js |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 1-8               
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.166 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts test "--coverage"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-01T08_41_32_538Z-debug.log
The command "docker run -e CI=true test/react-docker npm run test -- --coverage" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

this is '.travis.yml' file.

```
sudo: required

language: generic 

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - echo "start Creating an image with dockerfile"
  - docker build -t test/react-docker -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run -e CI=true test/react-docker npm run test -- --coverage

after_success:
  - echo "Test Success"
```

i guess , maybe because of 'sudo' in '.travis.yml'file. that is command in ubuntu.

anyway i dont know how to solve this issue :(

i hope you help me :)

Comment: It appears one of your tests is failing! If you created your project using `create-react-app`, run `npm test` locally to run your tests and then fix the reported error in your code.

Comment: omg... relally thx i was really so stupid lol
i solved the issue by ur comment really thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If your issue was resolved, consider deleting this question as it was simply the matter of debugging your tests and, as it stands, it isn't likely to be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You might have removed learn react text from the app body that comes when react app is created. You need to remove this test.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).